# Trying to add hyperlink to excel cell but result is filepath

Tags: java, excel, xssf

I'm trying to add a hyperlink to excel cell using java as follows.

```
XSSFCreationHelper helper= xssfWorkbook.getCreationHelper();
XSSFHyperlink url_link=helper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_URL);
cell.setCellValue("some Text");
url_link.setAddress("www.google.com");
cell.setHyperlink(url_link);
```

But when I created the excel file, cell contains wrong url, something as follows.

```
file:///C:/Users/..../www.google.com
```

What is I'm doing wrong here? Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make it work just add `http://` in-front of your url.

eg: `http://www.google.com`